# How to see full content of long strings with var_dump() in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, var-dump

I have an array with some strings like

```
$array = array("string1","string2","string3");
```

But those strings are very long, with a length of 2000+ sometimes. So when I do

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

It shows me something like

```
string 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz '... (length = 994)
string 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy '... (length = 1287)
string 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx '... (length = 1718)
```

Instead of the full string. How can I see the whole content of my array? And for those who will ask, it contains HTML tags, so that's why I don't write `echo $array[string];`

Comment: Sounds like you're using xdebug. If so, please confirm, and I can answer this question.

Comment: How can I know if I'm using it? I'm in localhost with wamp if it matters

Comment: Add `phpinfo();` to a script and search the results for "xdebug".

Comment: Yes, it has xdebug 2.2.5

Comment: That's not standard var_dump() output: https://eval.in/487235

Comment: @AbraCadaver in wamp localhost it does what I said, which I don't understand why

Comment: what about `echo var_export($array, true)` (then look at the source code because of html tags) ?

Comment: @Mat var_export() render HTML, which is not what I want

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You are using xdebug, which overloads the default `var_dump()` to give you prettier and more configurable output. By default, it also limits how much information is displayed at one time. To get more output, you should change some settings.

Add this to the top of your script:

```
ini_set("xdebug.var_display_max_children", '-1');
ini_set("xdebug.var_display_max_data", '-1');
ini_set("xdebug.var_display_max_depth", '-1');
```

From [the docs](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings):

> **xdebug.var_display_max_children**
>
> *Type: integer, Default value: 128*
>
> Controls the amount of array children and object's properties are shown when variables are displayed with either xdebug_var_dump(), xdebug.show_local_vars or through Function Traces.
>
> To disable any limitation, use -1 as value.
>
> This setting does not have any influence on the number of children that is send to the client through the Remote Debugging feature.
>
> **xdebug.var_display_max_data**
>
> *Type: integer, Default value: 512*
>
> Controls the maximum string length that is shown when variables are displayed with either xdebug_var_dump(), xdebug.show_local_vars or through Function Traces.
>
> To disable any limitation, use -1 as value.
>
> This setting does not have any influence on the number of children that is send to the client through the Remote Debugging feature.
>
> **xdebug.var_display_max_depth**
>
> *Type: integer, Default value: 3*
>
> Controls how many nested levels of array elements and object properties are when variables are displayed with either xdebug_var_dump(), xdebug.show_local_vars or through Function Traces.
>
> The maximum value you can select is 1023. You can also use -1 as value to select this maximum number.
>
> This setting does not have any influence on the number of children that is send to the client through the Remote Debugging feature.

Comment: can also be put in php.ini file using the same config setting names, e.g. `xdebug.var_display_max_depth=-1` works, but recommend only for local dev sites

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Good point. That said, xdebug shouldn't be used at all in production; it's a performance killer.

Comment: @EdCottrell true that^^ should only be on local, and dev at a push :)

Comment: Please note that on PHP 7.1 second argument should be string, not integer.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, using `var_dump` might be very tedious when working with long strings. 
Instead outputing the result on the browser, you can use the terminal.
Another solution is to output the result on a text file using `file_put_contents` or similar. Then open the file and check the result.

Answer (score 2):

Use `print_r()` instead of `var_dump()` for long strings.

Answer (score -4):

Something like this would also display any html tags in the values:

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
    echo($key.':<br /><pre>'.htmlspecialchars($value).'<pre><hr>');
}
```